# How to develop a boolean search engine using python

Tags: python, algorithm, search, model, boolean

Any link for python-based boolean search engine, which searches a boolean query from a set of files. For example, I have 100 files namely file 1, file 23232, file433 etc and I want to search is there any file named file 63. Kindly help its about a project.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, please see [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: It will be a program or do you need for this moment? I am used to do this in terminal (Bash) for exemple: `find -type f -name '*63*'`

Comment: If you have a set of files you can simply use `"file 63" in set_of_files`.